# display a message for user if the email recieved is in spam

Tags: html, email, spam, spam-prevention

kinda a tough question that might have a solution using HTML in gmail (or any other provier)

assuming you have sent an email from your server , the email is HTML formatted , user receives the email to his SPAM folder , when he reads the email , a portion of the message tells him that "This message has been displayed as spam" or "mark this message as not spam" , but if he receives the message to the inbox , this text is not displayed  .

been trying to do it using image alt text , kinda failed :( .

Comment: Can you clarify what your trying to do? I can't make heads or tails of this.

Comment: lets say i've sent you an email , if you open it from the spam folder , the content of the email will contain "you are in spam folder" , if you open it from your inbox , that "you are in spam folder" will not be displayed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either include at the bottom of each email "Please add user@example.com to your address book if this message has been marked as spam" or to use a 1x1px transparent image with ALT text reading the same. From a usability point of view, it's not really a problem to ask every user to whitelist your address, those who didn't have it marked as spam will ignore.

Answer (score 4):

You mean, you want to detect this from *within your E-Mail*?

That is impossible. The only thing coming close is indeed the `alt` text that would display if the image doesn't get loaded - but that is dubious because it probably isn't displayed by all clients. More than that is not possible, because there is no way for you to tell where the user is viewing your E-Mail from, and you have no possibility of interacting anyway.

Comment: There are indeed enough clients that prevent the display of (external) images to prevent spam.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for an author to modify an email based on it being detected as spam (or otherwise) after is has left the author's control.

Answer (score 0):

Simply not possible. I'm sorry.